# Make a POST request using AJAX doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, post

I've a pure javascript code and I need to send a JSON (that could be big so exceed the GET limit ....), so I'd like to use AJAX for the POST request.

My code is ...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Test POST via AJAX</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        var waypoints = [{
                "options": {
                    "allowUTurn": false
                },
                "latLng": {
                    "lat": 44.911434,
                    "lng": 7.671602
                },
                "name": "Corso Vinovo, Carignano, TO, Piemonte, Italia",
                "_initHooksCalled": true
              }, {
                "options": {
                    "allowUTurn": false
                },
                "latLng": {
                    "lat": 44.910167,
                    "lng": 7.676274
                },
                "name": "Il Tempio del Pane, Corso Cesare Battisti, Carignano, TO, Piemonte, Italia",
                "_initHooksCalled": true
              }, {
                "options": {
                    "allowUTurn": false
                },
                "latLng": {
                    "lat": 44.908034,
                    "lng": 7.675075
                },
                "name": "Banca Intesa, Via Ferdinando Salotto, Carignano, TO, Piemonte, Italia",
                "_initHooksCalled": true
        }];

        alert ('Waypoints --> ' + JSON.stringify(waypoints));

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "NewPage.php",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify(waypoints),
          success: function()
           {
            alert("OK ...");
           },
          error: function()
           {
             alert("KO ...")
           }
        })

       alert('After post request ...');

    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

and here you're the code of NewPage.php

```
<?php
    echo 'Waypoints ?????';
    print_r($_POST)
?>
```

Executing the code I can see that my AJAX code alert me "OK", but I can't see anything about my NewPage.php

I'm quite a newbye about this stuff, so sorry for banality ....

Any suggestions, example, jsfiddle, alternative?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cesare

Comment: what do you want to see from your NewPage.php?

Comment: you do not have any return var in your success callback.. It is supposed to fetch you the result from server side,put a die or exit after post print.

Comment: At the moment I'de like to see (echo ...), the JSON sent from the first html page, I'll put my business code after ....  Thanks

Comment: add `data` to your `success` like :- `success: function(data)` and inspect whats returned in `data`.

Comment: `$data = $_POST['waypoints'];
echo json_encode($data);` in php


`$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "NewPage.php",
          
    dataType: "json",
            data: {
                waypoints: JSON.stringify(waypoints)
            },
          success: function(data)
           {
            alert(data);
           },
          error: function()
           {
             alert("KO ...")
           }
        })` in ajax

Answer (score 0):

you should use die in php.

```
 <?php
       echo json_encode($data_to_pass);
       die;
    ?>
```

and in your javascript file you should use

```
success: function(data)
           {
            alert(data);
           },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using content type as **application/json**, you should json_encode the results back from your php page. Also use exit otherwise you will wonder why it is returning the whole page instead of just the json data.

```
echo json_encode($some_data);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your success callback to:

```
success: function(data)
           {
            alert(data);
           },
```

And you should see what's being echoed in the PHP page inside the alert once the AJAX post successfully finishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "NewPage.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {'waypoints':waypoints},
          success: function(resp)
           {
            //alert("OK ...");
           },
          error: function()
           {
             //alert("KO ...")
           }
        })
```

NewPage.php

```
            <?php
                echo 'Waypoints ?????';
                print_r($_POST['waypoints']);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing data: waypoints to data: {mydata : waypoints}. Passing your array directly causes jQuery to pass it in an odd format.http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 0):

You have not used the response returned from ajax success call back

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "NewPage.php",
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify(waypoints),
          success: function(response)
           {
            alert(response);
           },
          error: function(err)
           {
             alert(err)
           }
        })
```

also

```
alert('After post request ...');
```

is not going to execute after ajax call is completed, it'll be called exactly after ajax request made, independent upon it's done or pending. so do your stuff inside success or error